# directshow: framerate of sample 'Bouncing Ball'

Tags: directshow

Bouncing Ball is one of the sample in windows sdk, and it derives from CSourceStream.
I use GraphEdit and build this simple graph:

Bouncing Ball -> ColorSpace Converter -> Video Mixing Renderer 9

When graph is running, I see the fps is about 50 in property page of Video Mixing Renderer 9,
it's expected, however, if I unselected "use clock" option, the fps is 60.
According to document, the graph run as fast as possible when not using reference clock, so the fps should be more than 60 I think. How do I change the sample code that the fps will be more than 60 when not using reference clock?

Comment: Ensure that your graphics card is not setup to force vsync.

Comment: Thanks, by the way if I change "video mixing render 9" to "video render", fps can be more than 60, the problem seems causes by render's vsync setting.

Comment: Instead of removing clock, you can just remove time stamps from video frames and they will be presented as soon as possible.